# Nested Loop Algorithm - How indexes improve it?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, query-optimization, nested-loops

I'm looking at how nested loop algorithm works for joins in SQL, but not able to comprehend how indexes can improve its performance. From what I understand this algorithm is very similar to any standard nested FOR loop, how can index on one of the tables can help as all the rows in both the tables have to be looped over anyhow?

I'm a fresher engineer and my interested in DB optimisation has peaked after a production incident due to inefficient joins I introduced recently. Any resources to dive deep into this will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I would suggest adding an additional tag for the specific database type. i.e sql-server, mysql etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Nested loop" -- strictly speaking -- refers to two loops nested, which is what you describe.

Sometimes, the inner loop is replaced by an index lookup, which is O(log n) rather than O(n).  I don't really think of that as a nested loop join.  However, in some databases the explain plan still shows it as a nested loop.

Comment: Does that mean indexes of only one of two tables can be used in this algo? If so, do we have any optimisation where both tables' indexes can be used?

Comment: @bingoer . . . I think that when a "nested loop" shows up in an explain plan with an index lookup, then only one index is being used.  If both indexes are used, it should be some sort of "merge" join.

Answer (score 1):

They an not. The trick here is this:

> as all the rows in both the tables have to be looped over anyhow?

If that is the case, there is no index improovement.

If a loop on table a, though, does a LOOKUP on table b then it does not ahve to loop over the second table AT ALL - it loops over ONE table, then looks up on the second table. Which an index can SERIOUSLY help with.